# How to add data from arraylist into a SQL Server table using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have an arraylist containing strings. I want to add these data from index (0) until (2) into a SQL Server table.

This code displays data from index(0) to (2):

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim strA As String = "Bell-in-hospital"

        Dim arrayList() As String = strA.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For arr As Integer = 0 To 2
            RichTextBox1.Text += ("Index: [" & i & "] " & arrayList(arr).ToString & Environment.NewLine)
            i += 1        
        Next
```

I wanted to add it into db by using this code:

```
con.Open()

cmd = con.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "insert into subjectIndex_TestTable values('" + arrayList(0) + "', '" + arrayList(1) + "', '" + arrayList(2) + "')"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()

MsgBox("Successfully inserted into DB")
```

Is this correct? I run above code and it says

> Additional information: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

May I know why this happened?

Comment: Take care to use the right syntax if you insert with values like this. Hint: I guess, your table have more than one column.

Comment: There's no `ArrayList` there.  An `ArrayList` is a specific thing.  What you have there is an array.  The question you're asking is not really a valid question.  The way you insert data into a database table is the same regardless of where the data comes from.  Learn how to insert data properly and then the source of that data will be irrelevant.

Comment: If you do the appropriate reading on the `INSERT` statement in SQL then you will learn that you can only exclude the list of columns that you're inserting into in very specific circumstances.  Your scenario clearly does not meet the requirements.  On an unrelated note, learn how to use parameters in ADO.NET.  Doing so will help you avoid all sorts of issues, including having your entire database deleted by a malicious user.

Comment: Also, with regards to the `RichTextBox`, you should not be setting the `Text` property repeatedly.  I would suggest populating a `String` array with the data and assigning that to the `Lines` property.  If you're not using RTF formatting then why use a `RichTextBox` at all though?  You can just use a `TextBox`, which also has a `Lines` property.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Assuming that your table has only one column (the error message means that it doesn't have three, which is what your SQL insert is attempting to do), then you need to close the brackets after each value (before your commas) and re-open before the next (before the single quote). However, please follow the advice of others here and learn how to do this with parameters instead.